# Пытаюсь сделать вкладки внутри виджета, но чтобы вкладки работали внутри основного окна и не понимаю как это сделать

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qlayout, qpropertyanimation

У меня есть выдвижной виджет и основное окно, хочу сделать вкладки или `QTabWidget` внутри виджета, но чтобы они работали с основным окном.

Я не знаю как это сделать и можно ли вообще так сделать?

Помогите пожалуйста, ниже пример кода:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class gg(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): 
        #основное окно
        MainWindow.setObjectName('MainWindow')
        MainWindow.resize(845, 535)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 
        self.widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: white;') 
        self.widget.setObjectName('widget')
 
        #виджет
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)                      
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 45, 535))
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background: silver;")                  
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")
      
        #Вкладки(ну или же QTabWidget)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.widget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 845, 535))
        #для перемещения вкладки
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)

        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "1")
        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab2, "2")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        lay.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 0))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.widget)  

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):             
        pass


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, gg):
    def __init__(self):                 
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.frame2.installEventFilter(self)                                     
        #размер виджета до и после наведения курсором
        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(45, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(200, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):  
        if self.frame2 is obj: 
            #анимация выдвижения                                                                              
            if event.type() == event.Enter:                                   
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            elif event.type() == event.Leave: 
                #анимация возврата                                 
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
             
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    p = MainWindow()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я понял вашу задачу так:

**q1295440.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1295440_functions import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 400))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")        
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 235, 35);")
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
      
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 0))
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)

        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Page 1", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)

        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Page 2", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Page 3", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
      
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("PAGE 1", self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #ba135d;")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("PAGE 2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("PAGE 3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #f7a440;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
       
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        # PAGE 1
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        # PAGE 2
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        # PAGE 3
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        
    # функция с анимацией выдвижения виджета путем наведения курсора
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.frame_left_menu is obj: 
            if event.type() == event.Enter: 
                UIFunctions.toggleMenu(self, 250, True)
            elif event.type() == event.Leave:  
                UIFunctions.toggleMenu(self, 250, True)

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1295440_functions.py**

```
from q1295440 import *


class UIFunctions(MainWindow):

    def toggleMenu(self, maxWidth, enable):
        if enable:
            # GET WIDTH
            width = self.frame_left_menu.width()
            maxExtend = maxWidth
            standard = 70
            
            # SET MAX WIDTH
            if width == 70:
                widthExtended = maxExtend
            else:
                widthExtended = standard

            # ANIMATION
            self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame_left_menu, b"minimumWidth")
            self.animation.setDuration(400)
            self.animation.setStartValue(width)
            self.animation.setEndValue(widthExtended)
            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
            self.animation.start()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

> можно ли убрать зеленые рамки?

---

> void QLayout::**setContentsMargins**(int `left`, int `top`, int `right`, int `bottom`)
>
> Sets the `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` margins to use around the `layout`.
>
> By default, `QLayout` uses the values provided by the style. On most platforms, the margin is `11 pixels` in all directions.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1295440_functions import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 400))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")        
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")    # + 35
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
      
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 0))
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)

        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Page 1", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)

        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Page 2", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Page 3", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
      
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)              # +++
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
#
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)              # +++
        
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("PAGE 1", self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #ba135d;")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)              # +++
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("PAGE 2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)              # +++
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("PAGE 3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #f7a440;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
       
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        # PAGE 1
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        # PAGE 2
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        # PAGE 3
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        
    # функция с анимацией выдвижения виджета путем наведения курсора
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.frame_left_menu is obj: 
            if event.type() == event.Enter: 
                UIFunctions.toggleMenu(self, 250, True)
            elif event.type() == event.Leave:  
                UIFunctions.toggleMenu(self, 250, True)

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно ли убрать зеленые рамки?

Comment: @ivapop да, я чуть позже обновлю ответ

Comment: @ivapop я добавил обновление

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @ivapop пожалуйста